# Encoding and Decoding using RLE and Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, run-length-encoding

I have been given a task in my Computer Science lesson to encode and decode ASCII art using RLE. It must output it like "07A05B08C11D" for AAAAAABBBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDD". It must show 0 before numbers/amounts under 10 but I cannot find a tutorial/explanation on how to do this - they do not explain the 0's. Additionally it must take the ASCII art from a text file not input in IDLE. It must also reverse this process with an input using 0's.

Any help with this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for the run-length encoding and an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) for formatting single digit numbers:

```
from itertools import  groupby

s = "AAAAAABBBBBCCCCCCCCDDDDDDDDDDD"

result = ''.join(f'{sum(1 for _ in group):02}{k}' for k, group in groupby(s))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
06A05B08C11D
```

This statement `sum(1 for _ in group)` is for counting the numbers of element in each group.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly new to Python but we got set this task prematurely - we should of had another 8+ months or learning Python before this but our teacher is new so thought that we had already learnt what we needed to. Anyway this is great, thanks again!

Comment: @JoeHawkins Glad I could help.

Comment: It seems I have run into a bit of a snag. It encodes perfectly except for one detail - every new line it encodes it adds '01' to the end of it. So it is meant to output "01,01a01d57801d01a01," but it actually outputs "01,01a01d57801d01a01,01". Notice the additional '01'. It does this on every line and I don't know why. This is all I need to fix to make it perfect, thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @JoeHawkins Without any more information about your input format, I'm afraid I cannot help you

Comment: I'm giving it a .txt file with an ASCII art image inside of it (multiple lines). I'm guessing the extra 01 is probably from the line ending in the text file?

Comment: To give some more context, the user enters the file path, it is opened and modified using the code you provided, then output into another txt and printed.

Comment: @JoeHawkins the code is meant to be use by line, it assumes an input in the same fashion as the `s` of the example.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense! I tried implementing it in a pretty stupid way. I'll fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoeHawkins If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted

Comment: Accepted. Thanks again.